# How to display Tabs in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to Create a MVC application which will contain 3 tabs on a page and each tab will hold a different web grid. If any one is aware of this than please guide me.

Comment: I think you should look at some client-side coding to do this sort of manipulation in a single view.  The other alternative is use RenderPartial.  Let me know if you need further guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in addition to @heads5150's answer have a look at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs

Comment: By this i got exact idea for displaying any type to tab look.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would be a starting point for you to research using jQuery UI to help with the UI requirements of a tabbed interface.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Th following will help with the web grid requirement

http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/10/08/using-the-webgrid-helper-in-asp-net-mvc-3-beta.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much... Indeed this is really close to what i want .